# Is it asymptotic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

A sequence is:
x, $\ xlnx,$ $\ x^2 $, $\ x^2lnx $, $\ x^3 $ ... 
as x goes to infinity.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\phi_{n+1}(x)}{\phi_n(x)}=0.$$

I have a problem when n is odd or even. How to solve it?

Comment: Just put in $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\phi_{n+1}(x)}{\phi_n(x)}=0$ once $n=2k$, and once $n=2k+1$. If both cases are true then it is asymptomatic

Comment: $\ lim(x^klnx)/x^k = infinity. $ So it is not asymptotic sequence

Comment: if k is even then k - 1 is odd. And above limit goes to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 cases: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\phi_{2k+1}(x)}{\phi_{2k}(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{x^k\ln x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac x{\ln x}\longrightarrow \infty$$ already here you can see that the sequence is not asymptomatic.

If this was asymptomatic you would have to also check the second case:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\phi_{2k}(x)}{\phi_{2k-1}(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^{k}\ln x}{x^k}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {\ln x}1\longrightarrow \infty$$ and again this means this is not asymptomatic sequence.

If in all of the cases(here you have only 2)  it was true that the limit of the ratio goes to $0$ then it was asymptomatic sequence. Here you see that none of the cases hold this property so it is not asymptomatic (actually we could have stopped after one case)

Comment: As I know they both have to go to zero. But in each case, it goes to infinity. So It is not asymptotic, right?

Comment: I am a bit confused with it. You say that, If both of them go to infinity then it is a asymptotic sequence.

Comment: Maybe I said it a bit confused, I meant if both goes to $0$. I'll edit it to be more clear

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is clear